# How to specify amount of parallel link jobs bazel does, separate from build jobs?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel, build-system

I'm attempting to build Tensorflow from source with debug symbols, using the command:

```
bazel build -c opt --config cuda -c dbg --config=v2 --strip=never //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

However, every time I have tried it fails because the linker gets killed, likely due to exceeding memory usage due to parallel "ld" processes.

I can of course try the whole Bazel build process with only one core, but building would take a huge amount of time. I'd like to tell Bazel to only execute one job (similar to `-l 1` make flag) for linking, but use all my cores for building. Is there any option to do that?

I thought of running the build, allowing it to fail then running it with only one core again. However, it seems everytime the linking fails, starting a new build with the same command begins rebuilding everything from scratch for the tensorflow// target, and so I have to wait around 9 hours since I'm only using one core. Is this standard ?

Comment: An alternative would be to add cupious amounts of swap space to your machine. That will also be dog slow (but only while many linkers are running concurrently). Might be a simpler solution (or maybe not, but it's at least an option). Or just throw money at the problem and buy more RAM 

Comment: When trying to build [Apollo](https://github.com/apolloauto/apollo) (a huge autonomous driving project which uses Bazel) on a 16GB 6-core i7, the linker would often run the system out of memory and crash the build (and lock up the machine for a while as well).  The swap space hint was very helpful as Ubuntu 18.04 had set up only a 1GB swap partition. I [switched to using a 16GB swap file](https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/) and can now build the entire project successfully. Of course adding RAM would also help but enlarging swap was fast, easy, and free.